# JQueryMobile radiobutton for select how upload picture by link or browsing files

Tags: jquery, html

how I can solve this problem?

I want manage:

- no picture
- give picture by browse file
- give picture by url

but browse `button` doesn't work as you can see by **[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsaeuamk/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="yourCredentials" data-role="page" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h1>Login/Register</h1>

  </div>
  <div data-role="content">

    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
      <input type="radio" name="upload-locandina" id="upload-locandina-no" value="null" checked="checked" />
      <label for="upload-locandina-no">Nessuna immagine</label>

      <input type="radio" name="upload-locandina" id="upload-locandina-file" />
      <label for="upload-locandina-file">Da File
        <input type="file" class="upload-locandina-file" style="display:none;" />
      </label>

      <input type="radio" name="upload-locandina" id="upload-locandina-link" />
      <label for="upload-locandina-link">Da link:
        <input type="text" class="upload-locandina-link" style="display:none;" />
      </label>
    </fieldset>

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input.upload-locandina-file {
  position: relative !important;
}

input.upload-locandina-link {
  position: relative !important;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#upload-locandina-no').click(function() {
  $('input.upload-locandina-file').hide();
  $('input.upload-locandina-link').hide();
});
$('#upload-locandina-file').click(function() {
  $('input.upload-locandina-file').show();
  $('input.upload-locandina-link').hide();
});
$('#upload-locandina-link').click(function() {
  $('input.upload-locandina-file').hide();
  $('input.upload-locandina-link').show();
});
```

Any solution?
Thanks!!! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your problem is because of your `html` structure. You have placed `input type=file` inside `label`, which is why its default action is prevented.

Try putting it outside `label` as below

```
<label for="upload-locandina-file">Da File
</label>
<input type="file" class="upload-locandina-file" style="display:none;" />
```

**[Here's the updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/hsaeuamk/5/)**

Everything should work normally and you can style it with few `CSS` properties to look like before.